# OkHttp disk cache not as fast as expected

Tags: android, caching, picasso, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp disk cache to store images for Picasso, and they definitely *are* being loaded from disk, but there's still a lag in time of a few ms when loading up a page with images. It really should be instant (verified with other apps). I've set a disk cache of 10MB via:

```
// A cache that will help us keep images on disk so we minimize calls to /get_picture
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    httpClient.cache(cache);
```

Can anybody help me understand why this might happen? I'm using:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(sessionManager.getUserProfileURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar)
            .error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mImageView);
```

to load them into the image.

If it helps, I've made my own PicassoSingleton that just enforces some authentication. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible that OkHttp is using conditional GET requests, in which case both the network and the cache are used. Typically this is the case when the cached responses don’t have `Cache-Control` headers that permit long-term caching.